# the word "menu" in the context of gaming

Tags: translation

The word for a food menu is 菜单 `Càidān`, sensibly translating as "food list."

But what would you call a game menu? I could only think of 选项 `Xuǎnxiàng`, but this "options", which may be a sub item in the game's menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`菜单` in Mainland China, `选单` in HK/Taiwan are the standard translations for `menu` in Computer Software, no matter it's in a game, a line-of-business application or a utility.

`Main menu` is translated into `主菜单` in Mainland China and `主选单` in HK/Taiwan.

And you're right about `选项` is referring to `options` or `settings` menu, which is usually a sub item in the main menu.

Searching Google for '游戏主菜单' or '游戏主选单' you'll get plenty of examples.

Comment: Perfect. +1 for the additional context and examples too.

Comment: `Settings` is always translated to `设置`, and `Preferences` to `首选项`.